# How to specify the number of pages shown?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, pdo

Pagination PHP code:

```
<?php

//Connecting To The DB And Fetching Number Of Rows.
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM locations');
$stmt->execute();
$count = $stmt->rowCount();
$values = $stmt->fetchAll(); 

//Check If Page Number Is Set To Specific Value.
if (isset($_GET['pageno'])) 
{
    $pageno = $_GET['pageno'];                                //Current Page Number.
    $no_of_records_per_page = 100;                           // Number Of Rows Per Page.
    $total_pages = ceil($count / $no_of_records_per_page);  //Total Number Of Pages.
    $offset = ($pageno-1) * $no_of_records_per_page;       //Starting From. 
} 

//If Page Number Not Specified The First Page Will Be Shown.
else 
{
    $pageno = 1;
}

?>
```

HTML code beneath it:

```
<ul class="pagination">
//First Page.
<li>
    <a href="?pageno=1">First</a>
</li>
//Previous Page.
<li>
    <a href="<?php if($pageno <= 1){ echo '#'; } else { echo "?pageno=".($pageno - 1); } ?>">Prev</a>
</li>
<li>
    //Loop Through Pages.
    <?php
        for ($i=1; $i <= $total_pages ; $i++) 
        { 
            echo '<a href="?pageno='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>';
        }
    ?>
</li>
//Next Page.
<li>
    <a href="<?php if($pageno >= $total_pages){ echo '#'; } else { echo "?pageno=".($pageno + 1); } ?>">Next</a>
</li>
//Last Page.
<li>
    <a href="?pageno=<?php echo $total_pages; ?>">Last</a>
</li>
```

It's showing all the pages:

```
First Previous 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 Next Last
```

But if there are many pages it would be missed up.

I want to show specific number of pages like 5 or 6:

```
First Previous 1 2 3 4 5 .. .. 8 Next Last
```

Is it possible ? Is there is a library / plugin for that?

Comment: No need for a library. A simple if statement inside the for loop would decide which page numbers to display or hide.

Comment: As a hint: look at [**Laravel's pagination view template**](https://github.com/illuminate/pagination/blob/master/resources/views/default.blade.php) as a reference

Answer (score 0):

Best use Data tables which will process the data server side, which will be your ajax call and data will load on click on next or on pagination. it will reduce the load of getting data at one go and you do not have to write separate code for the pagination too.
Refer below link.

https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want displayed for the "extra" page number, change what is echoed in the if statement:

```
//Loop Through Pages.
<?php
    for ($i=1; $i <= $total_pages ; $i++) 
    { 
        if($total_pages > 8 && $i > 6 && $i < $total_pages) {
            echo '..';
        } else {
            echo '<a href="?pageno='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>';
        }
    }
?>
```